# Expanding Macro into more then one line

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

For example:

```
void foo();
void bar();
#define  CALC(a) \
do{ \
    if(a){ \
    foo();} \
    else{ \
    bar(); \
    } \
}while(false)

bool a = false;

void ree(){
   CALC(a);
}
```

The above example is equivalent to.:

```
#define  CALC (a)  if(a){ foo(); } else{ bar(); }

if(a){ foo(); } else{ bar(); }
```

I'm looking for a possibility to expand the macro to more then one line. For example:

```
void ree(){
    bool a = false;
    do{ 
        if(a)
        { 
           foo();
        } 
        else
        {
           bar(); 
        } 
    }while(false)
```

I need it because I want to parse the source code after the preprocessor, and I need some macros to be expended to more then one line.
Is it even possible? How?

Comment: we expect you to test the code before posting. it's a small issue, not relevant to the main problem, but still....

Comment: Run the preprocessor output through a code beautifier?

Comment: @remyabel - I actually need it to appear in the source code as a separated lines.

Comment: If your parser depends on newline characters, it's broken.

Comment: I would try to avoid macros - they cause more suffering than good. Use them with advisement.

Comment: (I deleted my last comment after a few seconds). Anyway, I've now just edited the question to correct the placement of the semicolons. It's not directly relevant to the original question, but it's important to *never* have semicolons at the end of a macro definition. A multi-statement macro should be of the form `do {   ....   } while(0)`

Comment: Why do you care? The preprocessor is generally inside the compiler, and gives a stream of tokens

Comment: Another issue to consider is to think what would `__LINE__` mean if macros could expand to multiple lines? `assert` prints the line number where the error occured, but this would be incorrect if macros expanded to multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about any way to make the preprocessor to insert a newline into macro expansion. The only solution I imagine is that you insert a specific string into macros, then after preprocessing, replace those strings by newline.

```
#define  CALC(a) NEWLINE\
do{ NEWLINE\
  if(a){ NEWLINE\
  foo();} NEWLINE\
  else{ NEWLINE\
  bar(); NEWLINE\
  } NEWLINE\

bool a = false;

void ree(){
  CALC(a) 
}
```

if you are on a Linux, you can then compile with:

gcc -E t.c | sed -e 's/NEWLINE/\n/g' | gcc -x c -